# pyramid-arima auto_arima order selection

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, forecasting, pyramid-arima

I am working on Time Series Forecasting(Daily entry) using `pyramid-arima` `auto_arima` in python where y is my target and x_features are all exogenous variables. I want best order model based on lowest aic, But `auto_arima` returns only few order combinations.

[image] PFA where 1st code line (`start_p = start_q = 0` & `max_p = 0`, `max_q = 3`) returns all 4 combinations, but 2nd code line(`start_p = start_q = 0` & `max_p = 3`, `max_q = 3`) returns only 7 combinations , din't gave (0,1,2) and (0,1,3) and others, which leads wrong model selection based on aic. All other parameters are as default e.g `max_order = 10`

Is there anything I am missing or wrongly done?
Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You say error_action='ignore', so probably (0,1,2) and (0,1,3) (and other orders) gave errors, so they didn't appear in the results.
(I don't have enough reputation to write a comment, sorry).

Comment: I guess, because of stepwise = TRUE, as stepwise regression is an automatic process and involves no human intervention. It might be achieved by observing statistical values.

Answer (score 0):

The number of models autoarima trains is based on the data you feed in and also the `stepwise= True` if it is True autoarima uses a proven way to reduce number of iterations to find the best model and it is the best 90% cases unless data is very varying.
If you want the rest of models also to run as it isnt taking alot of time to execute try keeping `stepwise=False` where it trains with all possible param combinations.

Hope this helps